# c# Rest GET Endpoint with GetOne and GetAll

Tags: c#, rest

I have a very simple endpoint as an example

`/users/`

to obtain all users, which returns an array of N elements (maybe 0 elements if no users)

this is implemented on one specific method

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/users")]
public void getUsers() { ... }
```

But then, I need to get a user by id, so I would need another API endpoint. The question is, should I implement this on the same method, or a separate one?

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/users")]
[Route("api/users/{id:int}")]
public void getUsers(int? id) { ... }
```

In this case, my return is different, a single user or a `NotFound` instead of an array.

So I was wondering if this should be implemented as a single method (and reuse code) or 2 different methods.

Comment: Well you have different return types (`User` vs `IEnumerable<User>`) which suggests different methods. But this question is opinion based I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 different methods in case if response is going to be different. It looks like one method is to get all users details and another is to get specific user details based on user id.